# Physical interpretation of unbounded trace class linear maps

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-information, trace

Quite generally, quantum states are defined to be positive, trace-class linear maps with trace equal to one on a complex separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. If we require that these trace-class linear maps be bounded, then they are linear functionals on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ in particular that satisfy the properties above. However, I found an example of a trace-class linear map $A$, with domain $\mathcal{D}_{A}=\mathcal{H}$, that is unbounded, and I find this interesting. In the mathematical literature, only bounded trace-class linear operators are discussed. Is there a particular reason for that? I will provide my example as a proposition.

**Proposition:** There exists at least one unbounded linear map $A:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$, which is of trace-class.

**Proof**: Define $A$ on the basis by $A(e_n)=n e_{n+1}$ then extend linearly.  $A$ is an unbounded operator with domain $\mathcal{D}_{A}=\mathcal{H}$ and it is of trace class, since:
\begin{equation}
Tr(A)=\sum_{i=1}^{\text{dim}(\mathcal{H})} \langle e_i, A(e_i) \rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{\text{dim}(\mathcal{H})} \langle e_i, i e_{i+1} \rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{\text{dim}(\mathcal{H})} \langle e_i, e_{i+1} \rangle=0.
\end{equation}
Of course, this map is not considered to be a legit state in quantum theory, as its trace is not one. However, does there exist an unbounded linear map $B$ with $\mathcal{D}_{B}=\mathcal{H}$, which would qualify as a quantum state? What would be its physical interpretation?

Comment: You have not shown that $A$ is trace-class - that the naive expression for the trace converges in one particular basis is *not enough*. In fact, the usual definition of trace-class only applies to bounded operators since it involves $\lvert A\rvert$, the "square root" of $A^\dagger A$. But the $A^\dagger$ part is exactly what fails for unbounded operators - if $A^\dagger$ is also everywhere defined, then $A$ is bounded. The trace-class operators are a *subset* of the bounded operators more or less by definition.

Comment: I am confident that the notion of being trace-class is basis independent. Could you provide a proof that the operator defined by me in a different basis has divergent expression for the trace?

Comment: The *expression* for the trace is basis-independent *if the operator is trace-class*! But you cannot show that an operator is trace-class by showing the expression converges in one basis (why do you think the usual definition involves $\lvert A\rvert$ and not just $A$?). As for your specific operator: Consider $e'_i := 2^{-1/2}(e_i + e_{i+1})$. Then $\sum_i \langle e'_i, Ae'_i\rangle = \sum_i 2^{-1}$ diverges.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. However, I did not see anywhere the definition of trace-class without boundedness. Could you perhaps write it down in full generality as an answer, then prove that trace class implies bounded, using the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem, as you mentioned? (Also perhaps this reformulated question rather belongs to the mathematics SE instead of physics)

Comment: Regarding your last question: No, irrespective of the trace-class business: Any positive semi-definite, densely defined operator on a complex Hilbert space is symmetric, and if the domain is the whole Hilbert space, then by Hellinger-Toeplitz it is bounded. Density matrices/quantum states are required to be positive semi-definite, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A positive everywhere-defined operator on a complex Hilbert space is necessarily bounded because it is symmetric, and symmetric everywhere-defined operators are bounded by [Hellinger-Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem). Hence an unbounded operator, trace-class or not, cannot be a positive operator and hence is not a quantum state. The unbounded shift operator $A$ from the question is explicitly not a positive operator because for $v = e_i - e_{i+1}$ we have
   $$ \langle v, Av\rangle = \langle e_i - e_{i+1}, ie_{i+1} - (i+1)e_{i-2}\rangle = - i < 0.$$
2. An operator is trace-class iff for $\lvert A\rvert$ defined as the positive operator such that $\lvert A\rvert^2 = A^\dagger A$ the trace
   $$ \mathrm{tr}(A) := \sum_i \langle e_i, \lvert A\rvert e_i\rangle$$
   exists. But the "polar decomposition" theorems used to guarantee the existence of $\lvert A\rvert$ assume $A$ is bounded (in another phrasing: the functional calculus for $A^\dagger A$ to obtain $\lvert A\rvert = \sqrt{A^\dagger A}$ needs $A^\dagger A$ to be self-adjoint, which fails for unbounded everywhere-defined $A$), so the very definition of trace-class does not make sense for unbounded operators.

Comment: With 1, I completely agree. With 2, I haven't seen this definition, but in your framework it is true. However, in Fredric Schuller's lectures, he does not define |A|, just says the domain has to be D_{A}=H and the trace has to exist in any ONB, and has to be equal in any ONB. In this framework, the operator that I provided, seems to fit. The counterexample of divergence, which you give seems not to be a counterexample, because the basis e'_i is not orthonormal. So, the conclusion is that Schuller defines wrongly the notion of trace-class?

Comment: Note: also on wikipedia, it is stated that the sum does not depend on the choice of ONB, not any basis.

Comment: @ProphetX I don't know Schuller's lectures but the definition via $\lvert A\rvert$ is perfectly standard (cf. eg. section VI of Reed & Simon I or any other standard text on functional analysis). It is also a standard result that trace-class operators are compact, and hence bounded (VI.21 in R&S); your operator is unbounded and therefore *cannot be trace-class*, any definition of "trace-class" that contradicts this is simply and plainly wrong. And again: You have *not* shown that the trace exists and is equal in *every* ONB - just that it exists in the one ONB you chose.